# Exact string search not working

Tags: support, search

I use this line a lot:

> Never store multiple values in one column

([Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19975411/575376), [Example2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19112544/575376), [Example3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19241581/575376))

[I tried to search for it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:575376%20%22Never%20store%20multiple%20values%20in%20one%20column%22) including it in quotes, but it returns no results which is wrong. What is going on?

Comment: I like the way you format that line in your answers. You get the sense of urgency across perfectly...at least I'll never do that again, promised!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact-phrase search doesn't stem or strip punctiation.

Add an exclamation mark and [suddenly you get matches](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A575376+%22Never+store+multiple+values+in+one+column%21%22) for example. 15 results on that one.

Make just the middle a phrase and add `never` and `column` and you can find [20 matches](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A575376+Never+%22store+multiple+values+in+one%22+column). That search uses:

```
user:575376 Never "store multiple values in one" column
```

Comment: Great. Didn't know that.

Comment: That makes no sense that it would work that way. One would expect that not including punctuation would make it find a match no matter what the actual punctuation is in the questions/answers. After all, a phrase without the punctuation is a subset of the same phrase with punctuation and is, therefore, found in the latter. Almost every search engine that I've ever used will find results in that case.

Comment: No, this makes total sense when you consider that this allows you to search for coding syntax otherwise stripped out.