# Why does a search for "[tag] difference <> !=" not show the most relevant result?

Tags: discussion, support, search

There was a [discussion about a question that was heavily downvoted on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210434/why-are-these-question-put-on-hold), presumably also because it didn't show any visible research effort.

However, when trying to replicate the research effort so I could berate the OP, I found SO's search doesn't work for this particular question. (Neither does Google's, but that's a different issue.)

The question is about the difference between the `!=` and `<>` operators in PHP.

There is, of course, a highly upvoted existing question:

[What is the difference between <> and !=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671785/what-is-the-difference-between-the-non-equality-checking-operators-and)

However, a search for

> php difference !=  <>

does not find it!

You have to wrap the `<>` in quotes for it to work, which is arguably too much to expect from a newbie.

Why is this?

Comment: Stemming; the eternal conflict between wanting to search for words without punctuation and code searches. Quoted text is matched against the unstemmed text.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32879/is-it-possible-to-search-for-punctuation-special-characters

Comment: This can also go the other way: [Exact string search not working](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209392).

Comment: Maybe the [Searching](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) page needs some extra clarification (although the second bullet does mention how to search for a specific phrase). This does assume people actually go there....

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, but there are differences between words with punctuation, and just symbols.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: In programming, that is not always true. Plenty of languages attach meaning to `.`, `?` and `!` right after words, not to mention quotes, brackets and braces.